# DotNetOpenAuth redirect to Homepage

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, openid, dotnetopenauth

After a user logs in with their Google profile I am trying to redirect them back to the home page, however it keeps redirecting to default.aspx.

The line above the return in the code below is what I am using to try to redirect.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Logon(string loginIdentifier)
{
    if (!Identifier.IsValid(loginIdentifier))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("loginIdentifier", "The specified login identifier is invalid");
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        var openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
        IAuthenticationRequest request = openId.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(loginIdentifier));

        // Require some additional data
        request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
        {
            BirthDate = DemandLevel.NoRequest,
            Email = DemandLevel.Require,
            FullName = DemandLevel.Require
        });

        request.AddCallbackArguments("http://localhost:5977/Home/About", "http://localhost:5977/Home/About");
        return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I was able to figure this out, no worries!

Comment: For posterity, it's nice if you post your own answer so others with this question can figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a callback argument doesn't control where the user goes when login has completed.  Rather, web.config sets the default redirect behavior:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms defaultUrl="/myhomepage"/>
    </authentication>
```

Ultimately this can be overridden in your controller where you call `RedirectFromLoginPage` to instead use `SetAuthCookie` and then redirect manually.  But you should typically have the right home page URL listed in your web.config file anyway, in which case the right thing happens.

Comment: This would work too! Ultimately I ended up redirecting to the home page from the switch statement I had in the non-overloaded logon function. Redirect("Home");

Comment: I don't see this web.config element on http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/help/configuration-options/ - where do I put the <authentication  ...> config elements?

Comment: You don't see it documented in dotnetopenauth docs because it's an [ASP.NET Forms Authentication setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/532aee0e(v=vs.100).aspx).